# c++11 std::hash function object classes thread safety

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety

In c++11 are the hash function class objects declared in `<functional>` thread safe? E.g., is it safe to call this function from multiple threads?

```
size_t hash1(const std::string& s) {
    std::hash<std::string> str_hash;
    return str_hash(s); 
}
```

or, if one has a global object `std::hash<std::string> str_hash_global;`, then is it safe to call this second function from multiple threads?

```
size_t hash2(const std::string& s) {
    return str_hash_global(s); 
}
```

Comment: Other considerations aside, make sure that the string itself is not being modified concurrently while its hash is computed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library promises that if you *only* call `const`-qualified member functions on a standard library object, the standard library code does not cause a data race (cf. [res.on.data.races]).

The standard template `std::hash`, as well as all its permissible specializations, as well as any user-provided functor that meets the `Hash` requirements ([hash.requirements]) must have a `const`-qualified call operator due to the requirements, and thus using the library-provided `std::hash` specializations should not cause a race. Moreover, due to [namespace.std], program-provided specializations must meet the same requirements.

Finally, I imagine that you would usually use the race-freeness guarantees by recursively appealing to `const` calls: If you multiple threads concurrently look up values in a map, they have to use the map's `const` interface to invoke the above library rule, but then the map only gets to use a constant value of the hasher (or a private copy), and so it can itself only perform race-free hash computations. Whether a racy non-const call operator exists is immeterial at that point.

Comment: `must have a const-qualified call operator due to the requirements` Which part of the standard requires it? I was looking for something saying this, and couldn't find it. There is "The value returned shall depend only on the argument `k` for the duration of the program", but that doesn't directly say "`operator()` must be const-qualified"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It says "`h` is a (possibly `const`) value".

Comment: Ah, yes, so it does. "`h` is a value of type (possibly const) `H`", to be precise. I suppose that still doesn't strictly preclude a class that provides two overloads of `operator()`, one const and one non-const (though it's not clear why anyone would ever want to do this).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Ah yes, that would be evil :-S

Comment: so I guess if I use `const std::hash<std::string>` that'll do it?

Comment: @hovo: Yes, that should do. Or `return std::as_const(str_hash)(s);` in C++17.

Answer (score 3):

The same "thread-safety" rules apply here as for all std::lib types.

The first version is guaranteed to be thread-safe because there are no variables shared between threads.

The second one is guaranteed to not have any data races if the `operator()` that gets called is `const`. It is unspecified whether the implementation provides a (potentially non-thread-safe) non-const overload of `hash<T>::operator()` in addition to the (required) const one. If your `global_str_hash` is const, or you cast it to const before using it, then you guarantee the const `operator()` will be used.

There is no reason to do the second version, it's just silly, but in practice it should be safe because no standard library implementation is likely to provide a racy non-const overload of `hash::operator()`, they will only provide a const overload, which must be thread-safe.