# Write generic c++ concurrent hashtable

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I need to implement a concurrent generic hash table using c++. I have several questions during implementation.

Q1: How can I implement the hash function for generic type? I am thinking maybe I can define a default one when key is integer type, but for other types, I can ask user to provide hash function. How to set default hash function? How can I allow the user to provide user defined hash function? Or any better ideas?

Q2: How to make the hash table concurrent, more efficient? Currently I put lock for each operation. In this case, I think each time only one thread can access the hash table which is not efficient.

Thanks!

Below is my code(not complete):

```
template<typename K, Typename V>
class HashMap{
  vector<list<pair<K, V>>> data;
  int capacity;
  mutable mutex mtx;

  HashMap(){
    this->capacity = 100;
    HashMap(capacity);
  }

  HashMap(int capacity){
    this->capacity = capacity;
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
      data.push_back({});
    }
  }

  HashMap(const HashMap<K, V> &other){
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(other.mtx);
    data = other.data;
  }



  HashMap& operator= (const HashMap<K, V> &other){
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(other.mtx);
    data = other.data;
    return *this;
  }

  ~HashMap {}

  int hashFunction(K key){ //??

  }

  void put(K key, V value){
    int idx = hashFunction(key);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    for(auto it = data[idx].begin(); it != data[idx].end(); ++it){
      if(it->first == key){
        it->second = value;
        return;
      }
    }
    data[idx].push_back({key, value});
  }

  V get(K key){
    int idx = hashFunction(key);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    for(auto entry : data[idx]){
      if(entry.first == key){
        return entry.second;
      }
    }
  }

  void delete(K key){
    int idx = hashFunction(key);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    for(auto it = data[idx].begin(); it != data[idx].end(); ++it){
      if(it->first == key){
        data[idx].erase(it);
      }
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: See [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Comment: Are you going to make this container compatible with standard ones? If yes then I doubt it is possible to make it so.

Comment: First, make a non-concurrent one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++11 std::hash function object classes thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385854/c11-stdhash-function-object-classes-thread-safety)

Comment: There are a number of small problems with your code: no need to store capacity, as vector's track their own capacity; you can use vector.resize() instead of a loop of push_backs; you can't call a function `delete` because it's a reserved word - try `erase`; get must return or throw something when it can't find the key; for most flexibility you should get the caller to provide you with a hash function suitable for their key type, but you could provide a number of `int hashFunction(int key)`, `int hashFunction(double key)`, `int hashFunction(std::string key)` overloads as a simpler approach.

Comment: Regarding your actual questions, you can google "c++ simple hash function" if you want to write your own - too open-ended to explain as a sub-question.  You can let the use provide a hash function using either a `std::function<int(K)>` parameter to the constructor, or as a template parameter (sometimes known as a "policy" when it provides such implementation details).  For more throughput, provide functions that take can undertake larger actions while holding the lock: e.g. `void insert(const vector<pair<K, V>>& new_elements)`, `void erase(const vector<K>& keys)`.